# How to read Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I know its easy but unfortunately I'm stuck in it. I've a array like this:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 91
        [title] => final test sql question
        [description] => 
final test sql questions


        [status] => 1
        [testId] => 29
        [questionOrderNo] => 1
        [createdAt] => 2015-09-05 11:02:06
        [updatedAt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

)
```

How can i read its value like id and title...

Comment: try to do `print $a[0]["title"];` or `print $a[0]["id"]`

Comment: i tried this but gives following error:

Cannot use object of type Elegant\Result as array

Comment: in this case, do directly like this `print $var->title;` or `print $var->id;`

Answer (score 1):

That is a multidimensional array you can access it through its index. i.e array[numeric index][text reference]

```
$myarr = array(
    0 => array(
     'id' => '91',
     'title' => 'final test sql question',
     'description' => 'final test sql questions',
     'status' => '1',
     'testId' => '29',
     'questionOrderNo' => '1',
     'createdAt' => '2015-09-05 11:02:06',
     'updatedAt' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
     )
);
echo $myarr[0]['status'];
```

Comment: i tried this but gives following error:

Cannot use object of type Elegant\Result as array

Comment: The answer forgets to put a comma after every entry but the last one. Try that.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg the structure in the answer is from `var_dump` it's not proper array definition.

Comment: Oops my bad - should have realised that, was looking from the mobile app

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by:

```
echo $yourArray[0]['id'];
echo $yourArray[0]['title'];
```

If you want to access all values use 'foreach'

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $val)
{
 echo $val['id'];
 echo $val['title'];
}
```

Comment: i tried this but gives following error:

Cannot use object of type Elegant\Result as array

Comment: Maybe your array is an object of array.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

$id = $arr[0]['id']; and if they are many of those all you have to do is foreach($bigarr as $arr){
echo $arr['id'];
}